Google Sheets-Timestamp Add when cell is first edited
I have a sheet with 5 tabs, Called Adam, Bob, Cheryl, Dave, Earl where I want to add a permanent timestamp in column R the FIRST time a cell in column F is edited.
function onEdit(e) {
var col = e.range.getColumn();
if(col == 6) {
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,2).setValue(new Time())

function onEdit(e){
/* Using a conditional operator to assign the active sheet
when this function is ran without providing an event object, i.e.
when running from the script editor */
const sheet = e ? e.range.getSheet() : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if(sheet.getName() === 'TBD'){
sheet.getRange('R4').setValue(new Time());

 }
 }

Is what I tried. for some reason it adds the timestamp in column V, and it's only good for a single timestamp , which was supposed to be in column R cell 4. I need every row to have its own timestamp, I am expecting as many as 500 rows per tab
